# iOS Simulator could not find the SDK, SDK may need to be reinstalled

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, xcode4.2

Here I am stuck in another problem,am working on an iOS Application today and as i run my Application for iPhone 5.0 Simulator got some weird issue on that simulator only.
There were two window pop Over alert on my MacBook Screen when i was trying run again and again getting same issue for that simulator only.that pop over alert windows showing below quotation.

**"iOS Simulator could not find the SDK. The SDK may need to be reinstalled."
"The simulated application quit."**

[image: Look At the Below Image depict the same issue.]

It seems that this issue occurring due to the improper installation of that simulator.
Please help me by suggesting related to this issue.
Whether i have to reinstall that simulator again on my Xcode or need something else.

Any suggestion would be appreciated from the bottom of my Heart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this on coworkers computers and it was because they had dock icons not pointing to  Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app

I would try launching the simulator from that directory or deleting the Application/Xcode.app and reinstalling from the Mac App Store.