# nativescript Starting iOS Simulator Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to follow the nativescript setup on OS X:
http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter

`tns doctor` tells me: `No issues were detected.`

But when I run `tns run ios --emulator` after the build I get the error:

```
Starting iOS Simulator
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

What is my setup missing?

Comment: Did you add the platform ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solutions provided by te collegues I can also suggest the following when you have multiple connected devices/emulators and want to test on one specific:

- Check your currently started devices/simulators/emulators with

**tns device**
will return something like

```
│ # │ Device Name │ Platform │ Device Identifier   │ Type     │ Status    │
│ 1 │ vbox86p     │ Android  │ 192.168.56.101:5555 | Emulator │ Connected │
│ 2 │ iPhone 5    │ iOS      │ f5ae7a02a8ba77fa572 │ Device   │ Connected │
│ 3 │ iPhone 6    │ iOS      │ 03AEBB35-4EC4-4DCC  │ Emulator │ Connected |
```

- Select your desired device (copy its ID or Device Identifier) and run the following:

tns run ios --device ID

or

tns run ios --device deviceIdentifier

*for example:*

```
tns run android --device 1                // will run on Android device
tns run ios --device 3                    // will run on the iOS emulator
tns run ios --device f5ae7a02a8ba77fa572  // will run on the iOS device
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I opened it up in xcode and realised that I didn't have any simulators installed.

try either or both of these to see if you can build it in xcode:

`open platforms/ios/*.xcworkspace/`


`open platforms/ios/*.xcodeproj/`

... and if your problem is the same as mine, fix it in xcode like this...

Xcode menu -> preferences -> Downloads tab -> then download the newest iOS simulator

For me it worked by downloading ios 9.1.

Answer (score 0):

it might be problem with the SDK. Possible solution for this problem you could find here: [iOS Simulator could not find the SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751259/ios-simulator-could-not-find-the-sdk-sdk-may-need-to-be-reinstalled) 
Another option could be to install NativeScript CLI again and to set up carefully **`JAVA_HOME`**, `ANDROID_HOME` and `CocoaPods` as it is described in the documentation: [Set Up the NativeScript CLI on OS X](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/ns-setup-os-x)